# SQL first date for the first specific occurrence of a value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, nested, min, looker

Suppose I have a table as follows:

| msg.tracking_number | msg.subtag_Message | msg.checkpoint_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345678 | Delivered | 2022-05-12 |
| 12345678 | In Transit | 2022-05-11 |
| 12345678 | In Transit | 2022-05-10 |
| 12345678 | In Transit | 2022-05-09 |
| 12345678 | In Transit | **2022-05-08** |
| 12345678 | Info Received | 2022-05-07 |
| 87654321 | Delivered | 2022-05-06 |
| 87654321 | In Transit | 2022-05-05 |
| 87654321 | In Transit | 2022-05-04 |
| 87654321 | In Transit | **2022-05-03** |
| 87654321 | Info Received | 2022-05-02 |
| 87654321 | Info Received | 2022-05-01 |

In the middle, you see the tags. 'Info received' is always related to the earliest date for a given tracking number. The amount of info received is always variable. Mostly it is just one info received per tracking number, other times it is more than one.

What I want is the date, related to the 'In Transit' tag. Specifically, the earliest (MIN) date from that 'In Transit'.

I already tried the following:

```
    SELECT  
    A.checkpoint_time,
    msg.subtag_message,
    msg.tracking_number,
    
    Case 
    When
    msg.subtag_message = 'In Transit'
    Then A.checkpoint_time
    End as test
    
    FROM `reporting-01.aftership.aftership_data`, UNNEST(msg.checkpoints) as A
```

However, This gives me all the dates related to the In Transit tags. Again The amount of In Transit related to one tracking number are variable. Mostly 3 but can be more.
I am thinking that I have to build a CASE within a CASE that only gives me that one, MIN, in transit date... but I have no clue on how to define this syntax...

The environment is a LOOKER SQL runner database, Original data comes from GBQ.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Apply rank to each checkpoint_time for each combination of tracking_number and subtag_Message and apply filter based on subtag_Message and the computed rank

```
WITH ranked_table AS (
  SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY tracking_number, subtag_Message ORDER BY checkpoint_time) AS cp_rank
  FROM table1
)

SELECT * EXCEPT(cp_rank)
FROM ranked_table
WHERE subtag_Message != "Info Received" OR cp_rank = 1
```

###### Output:

| tracking_number | subtag_Message | checkpoint_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345678 | Delivered | 2022-05-12 |
| 12345678 | In Transit | 2022-05-11 |
| 12345678 | In Transit | 2022-05-10 |
| 12345678 | In Transit | 2022-05-09 |
| 12345678 | In Transit | 2022-05-08 |
| 12345678 | Info Received | 2022-05-07 |
| 87654321 | Delivered | 2022-05-06 |
| 87654321 | In Transit | 2022-05-05 |
| 87654321 | In Transit | 2022-05-04 |
| 87654321 | In Transit | 2022-05-03 |
| 87654321 | Info Received | 2022-05-01 |

Answer (score 0):

You should group by the `tracking_number` and `subtag_message`:

```
SELECT
    msg.tracking_number,
    msg.subtag_message,
    MIN(A.checkpoint_time) AS checkpoint_time
FROM `reporting-01.aftership.aftership_data`, UNNEST(msg.checkpoints) as A
WHERE msg.subtag_message = 'In Transit'
GROUP BY msg.tracking_number, msg.subtag_message
```